# Round or hard corners on a single vertices in 2D

Tags: vertices

I have an 2D object (eg. circle) and would like to modify single vertices and their angle. Very much like in any graphic software I would like to select one single vertice and convert it either in a hard corner or a "soft"/smooth corner.
Couldn't find that in Blender. Proportional editing and smoothing won't work.

Related to this question I would like to manipulate vertices by exact dimensions and find that sometimes this is hard to achieve. For example I would like to scale by an exact dimension.

Comment: User413734, The intent of the Blender stack exchange site is for each question to contain a single question, or if not for all of the questions to be very closely related. Your question related to manipulating vertices by exact dimensions is not closely enough related (in my opinion) and should be its own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mesh objects always have what you seem to be thinking of as "hard corners". When you're saying "like in any graphic software" I assume you're thinking about vector-based software like Inkscape or Illustrator which typically use Bezier curves.

If you want to manipulate points in a similar manner you would have to create Curve objects, not Mesh objects.

[image: Add Curve>Circle]

Answer (score 0):

Use subdivision surfaces. Create a mesh, make it a 2d line, and add vertices near corners to sharpen them. Move those vertices away to loosen them up. Basically how one would work with splines in other softwares.